# Angular Subject not listening to changes

Tags: angular, angular-material, subject-observer

I have a Mat table which is getting data by Http get. I populate the table initially once the page is loaded and then when a search is done. 
My Table gets Populated initially but when the data source is updated,table is not rendered with updated data. I am using subject to listen for any changes.
I can see the updated value in the console.

```
export class SearchTableComponent implements OnInit {

   displayedColumns = ['claim', 'firstName', 'dateOfBirth'];

   isBusy: boolean
   _persons : person[] =[];
   personObservalbe$ = new Subject<person[]>();
   constructor(private personexternalservice: PersonExternalService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.getPersons('','','','');//to load first 100 rows when the 
       pageloads 

     this.personObservalbe$.subscribe((result:person[])=>{
     console.log('init1');
     console.log(result);
     this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);

    });
 }


   //function called on button click  
  getPersons(searchClaim, Dob, lName, fName) {

   let searchClaimNo = searchClaim;
   let searchDOB = Dob;
   let searchSurname = lName;
   let searchFirstname = fName;
   var sDOB = "";

   this.isBusy = true;

  if (searchClaimNo == '')
    searchClaimNo = "empty";

  if (sDOB == '')
    sDOB = "empty";

 if (searchSurname == '')
   searchSurname = "empty";

 if (searchFirstname == '')
   searchFirstname = "empty";

 this.personexternalservice._searchForPeson(searchClaimNo, sDOB, searchSurname, searchFirstname)
  .subscribe( ( person$  => {
   this.personObservalbe$.next(person$);
   console.log(person$);
  })
 );

}

export class person {
  coalServicesId: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  pctId: string;
  claim: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
}
```

and

```
// Service called
_searchForPeson(claimsNo:string, DOB:string, surname:string, 
  firstName:string):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`api/Mockup/Search/${claimsNo}/${DOB}/${surname}/${firstName}`);
}
```

HTML 
  `<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="claim">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Claim</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.claim}}<a fxFlexFill class="mat-row-link"></a></mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.firstName}} {{element.lastName}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="dateOfBirth">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date Of Birth</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.dateOfBirth}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row routerLink="" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>`

Comment: Try BehaviorSubject

Comment: Instead of creating the object  in subscribe, you need to set the result set to dataSource.

this.personObservalbe$.subscribe((result:person[])=>{
  console.log('init1');
  console.log(result);
  this.dataSource.data = result;
});

Comment: I tried that earlier and it did not work. 
     this.personObservalbe$.subscribe((result:person[])=>{
       this.dataSource.data = result;
    });

Comment: If issue still exists then ask you to share the stackblitz

Comment: please create a stackblitz, it will be easier to tackle problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the object in subscribe, you need to set the result set to dataSource. Then refresh it too.

```
this.personObservalbe$.asObservable().subscribe((result:person[])=> {
   this.dataSource.data = result; 
   this.table.renderRows(); 
});
```

obviously, declare and initialise the dataSource globally. Declare the ViewChild too.

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
@ViewChild(MatTable) table:
```

Update the html too.

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Comment: I tried that earlier and did not work
     
     this.personObservalbe$.subscribe((result:person[])=>{
      this.dataSource.data = result;
 
    });

Comment: where do you define the dataSource? I couldn't see it in the code. Also can you show the html as well?

Comment: Apologies, I have defined the data source as   dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

Comment: You need to refresh the table too.

@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;

and inside the subscribe,
this.table.renderRows();

in your html,
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

Comment: I tried that as well earlier, still the same issue. The Problem is when person$ changes, personObservalbe should detect the change and fire subscribe method. however it only fires subscribe when the page loads and not when getPersons(...) is called by click. The value for person$ is definitely changing as I can see in the console